# Looking for one of my childhood fantasy books with a group of girls in a different world

Tags: story-identification, novel

The story was about a group of girls, I think 5, that all lived by a tree house or some sort of well. They all got coins in their mailbox and by using them they went to a different world. I don't quite remember the rest of the book, but I do remember one of the girls turning into a mermaid(?)

The book was at a 2nd-grade reading level and it was a part of a series.

Comment: When were you a child? [This,](https://www.amazon.com/Peacock-Door-Ancient-Pathways-Hidden/dp/B07YMG4QZ9/ref=cm_cr_srp_d_product_top?ie=UTF8), for example matches if you were a child five years ago

Comment: You could improve this Story-Identification question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/tips-for-asking-story-identification-questions) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.